# Permission To Access Resource error in Kiwi Tequila API GET /search

Tags: rest, permissions, kiwi

I am using tequila API to search for flights given a from and to date. My API Request is as follows:

```
const axios = require('axios');

let config = {
  method: 'get',
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: 'https://api.tequila.kiwi.com/v2/search?fly_from=LHR&fly_to=MJI&dateFrom=25/05/2023&dateTo=13/06/2023',
  headers: { 
    'apikey': '-YDB6i895qUbvkh2NWKL4o62_Nn2JFnT'
  }
};

axios.request(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

My response is:

```
{
    "error_code": 403,
    "message": "You don't have permission to access this resource"
}
```

I am using the following documentations:

- https://tequila.kiwi.com/portal/docs/user_guides/booking_api__general_information_
- https://tequila.kiwi.com/portal/docs/tequila_api/search_api

When I use content-encoding gzip, it doesn't process my API and says:

> "Error: Cloud agent is unreachable"

Also, in the first URL, it says:

> Use a proper content type in the headers for all requests to Tequila API: Content-Type: application/json
> Use your API key in the headers for all requests to Tequila API: apikey: yourapikeyvalue
> The responses of our API are G-zipped and you need to unpack them by using the proper response header encoding: Content-Encoding: gzip
> Please use the booking_token throughout the whole Booking API flow that you received in the /search response. The booking token cannot be older than 30 minutes.
> The date and time in the Booking API are in the iso timestamp format

In my understanding, this means that the first API I should call is the /search API where I will get the booking token in the response.

My goal is to book/check flights and hence, develop a flight booking application for Libya.